# Count age groups in Java

Tags: java, sql

I have a SQL table with `age` and `name` of `customers` and want to count the number of customers within the following age groups

`18-30`
`31-45`
`46-60`
`61 and above`

Any idea how do I go about it?

Comment: have you already set the code for connecting to database? if yes you can use the COUNT sql method and WHERE to specify which grade you are counting

Comment: If you want to do it in the database entirely, you need to say which database; this is going to be a "group by" query where the "group by" is a switch statement that assigns values 1, 2, 3, ... to each age range.

Comment: The title implies you want to solve this using java but the body of the question leans towards an sql solution. Please clarify what are asking and add appropriate code to help explain your issue and show your current effort. This is after all not a free code writing service

Answer (score 0):

It's how you can do it in your database

```
WITH C AS(
    SELECT  name
            ,age
            ,CASE
                WHEN age >= 18 AND age <= 30 THEN '18-30'
                WHEN age >= 31 AND age <= 45 THEN '31-45'
                WHEN age >= 46 AND age <= 60 THEN '46-60'
                WHEN age >= 61 THEN '>61'
                ELSE NULL
            END AS AgeGroup
    FROM table
)
SELECT COUNT(AgeGroup) cnt, AgeGroup FROM C GROUP BY AgeGroup
```